# Ignoring duplicate tile updates in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I'm implementing queuing in medium, wide and large tiles in my universal app to show top 5 news headlines. In large tile, I'm showing 2 headlines at a time, so if there are 5 headlines, there will be 5 medium and wide tiles, but 3 large tiles in the queue. Since while updating tiles, we need to provide payload for all tile sizes, I need to specify to ignore the large tile payload from the 4th and 5th update.

There is a `contentId` attribute in `binding` element, that we can (theoreticaly) use for this purpose ([msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212854.aspx)). However, it's not working in Windows 10. It used to work in Windows 8.1. Has there been any change in this mechanism in Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been fixed in the latest Windows Insider Preview **14295.rs1** and **14316.rs1**, it's possible to be delivered in the following released version.

You're welcome to join the [Windows Insider Program](https://insider.windows.com/) and give us feedback on our latest work.

Comment: I'm trying this in Windows 10 (version 1703 build 15063.296) and it still doesn't work.Is there any workaround to this? Or changed API?