# Ignoring large tile updates in Windows 10 App

Tags: uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, tile

I'm implementing queuing in medium, wide and large tiles in my universal app to show top 5 news headlines. In large tile, I'm showing 2 headlines at a time, so if there are 5 headlines, there will be 5 medium and wide tiles, but 3 large tiles in the queue. Since while updating tiles, we need to provide payload for all tile sizes, I need to specify to ignore the large tile payload from the 4th and 5th update. It's the same behavior that the native mail app does.

There is a contentId attribute in binding element, that we can (theoretically) use for this purpose ([msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212854.aspx)). However, it's not working in Windows 10 (I'm using version 1703 build 15063.296). It used to work in Windows 8.1. Has there been any change in this mechanism in Windows 10?

I had previously asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873209/ignoring-duplicate-tile-updates-in-windows-10-universal-app) an year ago using an older version of Windows 10 and came to know that it had been fixed in insider builds. However, it looks like it's still not fixed in latest GA release. Hence I'm putting the question again.

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since while updating tiles, we need to provide payload for all tile sizes, I need to specify to ignore the large tile payload from the 4th and 5th update.

For adaptive tiles, there is no need to provide payload for all tile sizes. You are able to provide the payload according to your requirement. So for your scenario, you should simply omit including the `TileLarge` bindings for the other two XML payloads like the following:

> - Notification 1
>
>   - TileMedium
>   - TileWide
>   - TileLarge
> - Notification 2
>
>   - TileMedium
>   - TileWide
>   - TileLarge
> - Notification 3
>
>   - TileMedium
>   - TileWide
>   - TileLarge
> - Notification 4
>
>   - TileMedium
>   - TileWide
> - Notification 5
>
>   - TileMedium
>   - TileWide

By only including the TileLarge binding in three of the payloads, the platform will only have three large tile notifications that it can display, and therefore the user will only see three notifications on large. This is exactly what the MSN News app does.

I'd highly recommend using this approach instead of `contentId` attribute since it results in a smaller XML payload which is simply more efficient. `contentId` attribute is considered obsolete and not recommended to use. If you do have a valid use of `contentId` that isn’t achievable otherwise, please let me know.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.